# javascript onclick is not working

Tags: javascript

I have an onclick event that works in IE and FireFox, but not in Chrome. Request your inputs on fixing this.

```
onclick="; var extras=actNoExtras();actHandleReturnValue(actOpenDialogEx('/SiteScope/UI/SelectTableColumns.do?tableId=rfw_monitor_report_monitor_table0_29_0'+extras, 'dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:450px;scroll:no;status:no;resizable:no;help:no;dialogtop=184.0;dialogleft=287.0', 'height=400,width=450,top=184.0,left=287.0,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=no,modal=yes','no','button.arrange.columns.table', 'true','act'), '');"
```

Comment: Please read this before asking something : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please define "is not working".

Comment: Also, it's cleaner to have a function within your script tags or a js file, instead of such a big inline javascript

Comment: You should not put whole javascript function inside the markup.  Just like you shouldn't put the whole content of an e-mail in the subject.  Write functions in a separate file; only call the function in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is it, but could it be due to the extra ';' at the beginning of the code? Also what do you mean by not working. Does the dialog box not open?

In Chrome, you can press F12 and click on the Sources tab to debug your code. If there is an error, you will find an X symbol inside a red circle, along with a text regarding the error.